# Need to call jquery function or vice versa

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

I have a jquery function that controls some css that sets state to active or not. It runs on a click event.  I need to have a similar function run when a php function runs (when the user searches with a form). The search term goes through a php function which will match the term with an id.  How can I set the state to active with the php function?
Here is a link to a test area

http://vtour.dev4.webenabled.net/tester/index.html

If you click an area, the selection remains active.  if you type a name in the lavender search box, and click the search icon, the  corresponding area does not become selected.

(attaching the search functionality file.  i know there is a bunch of junk in there but the section that corresponds to this example starts around line 149

The small lavender box next to the input line is the click/search icon

Thank you

Comment: have you considered either using jquery, or not using jquery? the mixture of code must become confusing at some point; continuity is +1. Also..you call jQuery twice in your site. which plays an issue. It also make look as if you call searchTerm.value, but you never pass `searchTerm` to function `getInfo()`, which should probably be function `function getInfo(searchTerm)`. and even if you dont want to pass it over, you would still need to declare `var searchTerm = $('input#searchTerm')` somewhere for this to begin to work.

Comment: I'm working on someone else's project that was left mid stream. PHP is nor my forte nor is jquery. Since this is working except for the sctive state, I'd like to attempt a fix

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this from PHP, you do everything through Javascript (and see Ohgodwhy's comment, especially the note about using jQuery or not using jQuery - you should use .ajax() or .post() for example).

To do it, the AJAX would return some flag to tell Javascript what blocks to turn on/off, as well as the text response. You can wrap all this up in a JSON object.

```
<?php

$returnArray = array('html' => 'HTML TO DISPLAY', 'blocks'=>array(1,3,4));
echo json_encode($returnArray);

?>
```

and in javascript use the JSON object elements to display the text, and then also turn on/off the right blocks. This bit will be easier in jQuesry as it handles the JSON object for you, so you'd only need response.html for the html bit, and response.blocks for the blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a javascript function by outputting a html script tag.

ie.

```
<?php
echo "<script  type=\"text/javascript\">runJavascriptFunction()</script>";
?>
```

So you could technically drop that into the response from your FetchData.php - but if it were me, I would do it all with jQuery:

```
$('#woodward-title-search-button').click(function() { //on button click
    var term = $('#searchTerm').val(); //the search term
    $('#room-'+term).css('background','red'); //or more nicely: .addClass('highlighted');
    //load the response of fetchdata into #myDiv
    $('#myDiv').load('FetchData.php?searchTerm='+term); 
});
```

I would suggest communicating with your PHP in json and providing an ID of some kind to better target your div.. but this should work as a down and dirty solution.

Comment: Hi Chris, My problem with your suggestion is that the search term does not correspond to the room.  The routine is taking the search term and finding the id in the XML file.

Comment: Then I would suggest sending the ID back with your HTML as a seperate entity as Robbie showed you:
`<?php 
$returnArray = array('html' => 'The html for room 101 to return', 'id'=>'room-101');
echo json_encode($returnArray);
?>`  
  
and then on button click:  
  
`$.getJSON('FetchData.php?searchTerm='+term, function(data) {
  $('#'+data.id).css('background','red');
  $('#myDiv').html(data.hmtl);
});`